# Puppet console to show rpm packages it installed, including package dependencies

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet module that installs package A, which in turn depends on package B.

When I run puppet agent apply through my CI tool, it would output the puppet console log and everything about package A(version, config file, basically everything I wrote in my puppet module), however puppet asked YUM to install package B(due to dependency) and it was installed in the background, without a trace.

So I want to see the yum log for installing package B in my puppet console log, is there a way to do that? or a flag to turn on more detailed logging (other than verbose)?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be sufficient to make sure that Puppet explicitly requests the installation of package B before A?

Comment: I would add the relationship as mentioned above.  The interaction that you are describing is part of yum and not part of Puppet, so Puppet doesn't even know about it.  https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html

Comment: it would require a bit more work from us. Initially our goal was to try rely on yum but if it's something they can't do then we'll have to have explicitly install package B, thanks for the comment guys.